# Calculate Runge-Kutta order 4's order of error experimentally

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, numerical-methods

**The Problem**

Use the order 4 Runge-Kutta method to solve the differential equation

$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = -g + \beta e^{-y/\alpha }*\left | \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \right |^{2}
$

And corroborate that its global error is *O*(h^4)

**The Mathematical model**

I turn the problem into a system of order 1 differential equations:

- $
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = v 
  $
- $
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = -g + \beta e^{-y/\alpha }*\left | v \right |^{2}
  $

Therefore I define the discretization variables *u* (for position) and *v* (for speed) as:

- *v = f(v, u, t)*
- *u = g(v, t)*

And use the following increments for the Runge-Kutta method of order 4:

For *u*

- *k1v = h f(vn, un, tn)*
- *k2v = h f(vn + 0.5 k1v, un + 0.5 k1u, tn + 0.5 h)*
- *k3v = h f(vn + 0.5 k2v, un + 0.5 k2u, tn + 0.5 h)*
- *k4v = h f(vn + k3v, un + k3u, tn + h)*

For *v*

- *k1u = h f(vn, tn)*
- *k2u = h f(vn + 0.5 k1v, tn + 0.5 h)*
- *k3u = h f(vn + 0.5 k2v, tn + 0.5 h)*
- *k4u = h f(vn + k3v, tn + h)*

And use them in the RK4 expression for each of them:

$
u_{n+1} = u_{n} + \frac{1}{6} (k_{1u} + 2 k_{2u} + 2 k_{3u} + k_{4u})
$

$
v_{n+1} = v_{n} + \frac{1}{6} (k_{1v} + 2 k_{2v} + 2 k_{3v} + k_{4v})
$

NOTE: I first solve for *v*. To calculate the order of the error, I will solve *120 = h i* times with h = 0.1, h = 0.05 and use the result given for h = 0.001 as the "real" value, since I don't know the function that solves the ODE. Then I should corroborate that the absolute value of the "real" minus the result I got from h = 0.1 must be 16 times bigger than what I get when I substract the value I got from h = 0.05 from the "real" value.

**The program**

I'm using C++ to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

long double rungeKutta(long double h)
{
    long double alpha = 6629;
    long double beta = 0.0047;

    long double pos = 39068;
    long double speed = 0;

    for (int i = 1; h*i < 120; i++)
    {
        long double k1v = h * (-9.8 + beta * exp(-pos/alpha) * pow(speed, 2));
        long double k1y = h * speed;
        long double k2v = h * (-9.8 + beta * exp(-(pos + 0.5*k1y)/alpha) * pow(speed + 0.5*k1v, 2));
        long double k2y = h * (speed + 0.5*k1v);
        long double k3v = h * (-9.8 + beta * exp(-(pos + 0.5*k2y)/alpha) * pow(speed + 0.5*k2v, 2));
        long double k3y = h * (speed + 0.5*k2v);
        long double k4v = h * (-9.8 + beta * exp(-(pos + k3y)/alpha) * pow(speed  + k3v, 2));
        long double k4y = h * (speed + k3v);

        speed = speed + (k1v + 2.0*(k2v + k3v) + k4v)/6;
        pos = pos + (k1y + 2.0*(k2y + k3y) + k4y)/6;
    }

    return pos;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    long double errorOne = rungeKutta(0.01);
    long double errorTwo = rungeKutta(0.005);
    long double real = rungeKutta(0.0001);

    cout << fabs(real-errorOne) << endl << fabs(real - errorTwo) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**The results**

I find that the error is only reduced by HALF and not to the 1/16th of the first result.

What am I doing wrong?? I've run out of ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: I reproduced that problem. Just to make sure you made no programming mistake. Or we both did the same.

Comment: Thanks. Although that is for the worse, because we still don't know what the problem is :(.

Comment: and above the section "NOTE", you write
$ 1/6(k1+k2+k3+k4)$ which should be $ 1/6(k1+2 k2+2 k3+k4)$ like it is written in your code

Comment: is there a context for that equation?

Comment: @macydanim: Yes, it's another writing mistake in the post. Still, in the code you can see I factored that expression as 1/6(k1 + 2.0*(k2 + k3) + k4). The context is an object free-falling from high altitude and being subjected to the forces of gravitational pull (the -9.8 part) and the friction with the air (the function of *y*), all that having factored out the mass of the object.

Comment: Why is there inclusion of math.h and cmath? In C++, no .h variants should be used, and cstdlib is a dummy. Which compiler accepts _tmain?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be that you stop the loop the instant that $t=h*i\ge 120$ starting at `i=1`. Since the values of `h` used divide 120 (or any integer), this means that the number of steps performed may be one off from the required number due to numerical errors in computing `i*h`. This may give an error of size $h$ to the desired end time $120$ that is reflected in an error of size $h$ in the solution values.

So to make absolutely sure that the correct time is integrated, define `N=floor(120/h)`, so that $Nh\le 120<N+1$, loop for `i=0` to `N` with `dt=h` for `i=0` to `N-1` and in the last step `i==N`, set `dt=120-N*h`.

---

And indeed, if you follow the actual time during integration by introducing t=0 before the loop and updating t+=h inside the loop, you will find that the loop ends at `t==120-h`. An alternative to using the actual number of steps in the loop is to change the loop condition to `(i-0.5)*h<120`, so that rounding errors in `h` get compensated.

And then you will find that with `h=0.01` and `h=0.005` you already exceeded the tradeoff point where the accumulating floating point errors have a greater weight than the discretization errors. Comparing `h=0.4` and `h=0.2` results in the expected factor of 16.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined:

- u' = g(v, **t**)

but you use it as

- k1u = h f(vn, un)

instead of

- k1u = h g(vn, **tn**)

Comment: Yes, that was a writing mistake. You can see that I don't commit the same mistake in the other constants, nor in the code. I think.

Comment: So the error must be in the code for the `k`'s. Why don't you use functions to begin with so it matches the `RK4` method, and then inline the functions (or let the compiler do it for you).

Comment: I have, but the same behaviour stands.

Comment: @Heathcliff then update the code in the posting to show it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question of mine, but I'll answer since I see it has had some recent activity. The problem arose due to a misinterpretation of the problem and data given. After I re-ran all the simulations that fed the data to my function, it worked properly.

I don't recall if it was exactly order-4 that I got, so there may be some further problems with my function, but since it was close enough I didn't keep looking.