# How to implement a Runge Kutta method (RK4) for a second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

### problem

I have the following system of differential equations;
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = y \tag{1}\label{1}\\
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\lambda^2 x -A \tag{2} \label{2}
$$
where $\lambda$ and $A$ values are known values, we also further have the following initial condition values;
$$
x_0=x(0) = 0.5 \\
y_0=y(0) =\left. \frac{dx}{dt} \right\vert_{x=0} = 0.25
$$
1)How do I solve this system using RK4 method?

### My attempt

According to RK4 method we get
\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1}&=x_{n}+{\frac {1}{6}}h\left(k_{1}+2k_{2}+2k_{3}+k_{4}\right),\\
t_{n+1}&=t_{n}+h
\end{aligned}
where
\begin{aligned}k_{1}&=\ y_{n},\\k_{2}&=\ y_{n}+h{\frac {k_{1}}{2}},\\k_{3}&=\ y_{n}+h{\frac {k_{2}}{2}},\\k_{4}&=\ y_{n}+hk_{3}.\end{aligned}

2)After this, should I take $x_n$ or $x_{n+1}$ value for calculating $\eqref{2}$?

3)How do I use matrices to solve this system?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are coupled variables.  You have to update them both in each sub-step.  The way you are doing it here, you are trying to update $x$ alone.  This will give an incorrect answer.

Comment: Follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_methods#The_Runge-Kutta_method. The independent variable is $t$.

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256393/calculate-runge-kutta-order-4 for a problem with a correctly implemented RK4 for a second order equation. Or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/solving-coupled-odes-using-runge-kutta for a "condensed" implementation for second order systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question gets often asked. I'd like to speculate that there are 3 stages to understanding numerical ODE methods of the Runge-Kutta variety:

1. low-order methods applied to the scalar case,
2. transition to population models or mechanical second-order equations with 2 or 3 components,
3. the final insight that all methods for scalar first-order equations (except Kutta's 5th order method) apply without restriction to first-order systems, and that all ODE systems can be transformed to such first-order systems.

There appears to be a mental block to the idea to put all components of the system into one flat vector and then treat that vector like a scalar (in this context), also separating the numerical method from the dynamical model. I think that to overcome this block seems to be a short period in the learning curve. I believe that this is the reason that the example code in compendiums like wikipedia, rosetta-code etc. is mostly geared to the scalar case, phase 1 will not yet reliably understand the multi-component case and phase 3 knows that, up to some trivial overhead, the same code structure can be used, and the scalar-case code is a little more compact to write down.

Some links that contain the treatment of second order DE or systems of DE (like mechanical assemblages, celestial systems, ...) using the RK4 method

**Applying the vectorized RK4 method to a first-order system constructed from a higher-order equation**

- Example: [Solve fourth order ODE using fourth order Runge-Kutta method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615672/solve-fourth-order-ode-using-fourth-order-runge-kutta-method), apply RK4 in vectorized version like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333687/how-do-i-solve-a-2nd-order-differential-equation-for-projectile-motion-with-air

**Applying RK4 to the first-order system component-wise**

- Implementation example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224923/i-want-to-have-the-pendulum-blob-in-my-double-pendulum, this should demonstrate that this approach is not very suitable if the number of components increases

**Using the second-order structure of the equation or system**

- Theory: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/solving-coupled-odes-using-runge-kutta-method
- Implementation: <s>https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615672/solve-fourth-order-ode-using-fourth-order-runge-kutta-method,</s> [2-body gravity simulation with partitioned RK4 code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65097456/3088138)