# Doubt regarding solving a "system of" second order differential equations using 4th order Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

To solve a single 2nd order differential equation using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method, it is desirable to write the equation as two coupled first order differential equations. Two such coupled 1st order equations are of the general form:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x,y) \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=g(t,x,y)$$
We get the approximate solution $(x_n,y_n)$ at time $t_n, n=1,2,..$ via the iteration
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{h}{6}(k_{n1}+2k_{n2}+2k_{n3}+k_{n4})$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{6}(l_{n1}+2l_{n2}+2l_{n3}+l_{n4})$$
where
$$k_{n1}=hf(t_n,x_n,y_n)$$
$$l_{n1}=hg(t_n,x_n,y_n)$$
$$k_{n2}=hf(t_n+h/2,x_n+k_{n1}/2,y_n+l_{n1}/2)$$
$$l_{n2}=hg(t_n+h/2,x_n+k_{n1}/2,y_n+l_{n1}/2)$$
$$k_{n3}=hf(t_n+h/2,x_n+k_{n2}/2,y_n+l_{n2}/2)$$
$$l_{n3}=hg(t_n+h/2,x_n+k_{n2}/2,y_n+l_{n2}/2)$$
$$k_{n4}=hf(t_n+h,x_n+k_{n3},y_n+l_{n3})$$
$$l_{n4}=hg(t_n+h,x_n+k_{n3},y_n+l_{n3})$$

**QUESTION:**

**Now, I am trying to solve a system of 2nd order equations (e.g., two 2nd order equations).**

**Is it correct if I apply the same method in this case, i.e., can I write each 2nd order equation as two coupled first order equations? In such a case, two 2nd order equations can be written as four 1st order equations.**

Comment: Yes, that is correct so far. For details and simplifications in the second order case, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176684/how-to-implement-a-runge-kutta-method-rk4-for-a-second-order and links there.